# Why can't Selenium exeute a driver.get(URL) when busy loading another page?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome

I use Selenium to automate a task on a public website.

First, I login at https://somesite/login by entering username/password and then clicking login. After that I want to load another page (https://somesite/anotherpage).

This second step fails because after the first step the start page https://somesite/ begins to load and it takes some time to finish and `driver.get(someURL)` seems to not be executed if the browser is busy loading another page.

1. Why does `driver.get(someURL)` fail if executed while another page hasn't finished loading?
2. Do I really need to use wait.until(ExpectedConditions... (or are their better alternatives?) and verify that the https://somesite/ has finished loading before I load next page? That is not how a browser works when used "manually".

Comment: I think you should wait until the login page has completed it's thing, as it's is downloading cookies and what not to ensure that you have a valid session. I think what's going on is that, once you login, you immediately try to go to another page ( possibly without the cookies set ) this will return a `500` or at least a `401 Unauthorzied`, throwing an error on the selenium in return.

Comment: I have done stuff as switching between pages, using `driver.get(url1); driver.get(url2);` but I had valid sessions in both of them. Also, in terms of using it "manually", the user typically would not be able to click anything on the screen until it has loaded, unless the user changes the url manually.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar Which is the best way to wait for that? It is a pretty simple page.

Comment: `wait.until` is the best way to do that, wait until one element, that you know marks the page has been loaded ( probably a div tag or even some span tag ) has been completely loaded, which in turn implies that the page has correctly loaded ( atleast till the point that there are no session issues) , and then go ahead with the next steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this code to wait until your element is visible.

```
private void waitForVisible(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually have done some web-automatation projects in which i was opening multiple tabs using this code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");//open new tab
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));//switch tabs
driver.get("link_to_open_in_new_tab");
```

This was pretty fast so i suggest you try this...
Even if you wait for the previous page to be fully loaded you can easily switch tabs :

```
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabnumber));
```

With this code i have never faced issue opening new tabs